# Component Integration test the relies on another third party component not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am getting the following error when running an integration component test.  Any ideas why?  The only slightly weird thing is that the `{{input-mask}}` component is used from an [addon](https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-inputmask).

> TypeError: (intermediate value).on is not a function
>       at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:182304:7
>       at mod.state (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:152:29)
>       at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:14)
>       at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:5)
>       at requireFrom (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:123:12)
>       at reify (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:108:22)
>       at mod.state (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:151:17)
>       at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:14)
>       at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:5)
>       at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend._extractDefaultExport (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:66617:20)

Test:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('phone-mask', 'Integration | Component | phone mask', {
  integration: true
});

test('it can format landlines', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  this.set('value', 1111111111);
  this.render(hbs`{{phone-mask value=value}}`);
  assert.equal(this.$('input').val(), '(11) 1111 1111');
});
```

Component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from './template';
import { startsWith } from '../../utils/elm-helpers';

const  { Component, observer } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
  layout,

  // public
  value: null,
  format: '(99) 9999 9999',
  iconName: 'phone',
  disabled: false,

  valueUpdated: observer('value', function() {
    if (startsWith(this.get('value'), '04')) {
      this.set('format', '9999 999 999');
      this.set('iconName', 'mobile');
    } else {
      this.set('format', '(99) 9999 9999');
      this.set('iconName', 'phone');
    }
  })

});
```

Template:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-{{iconName}}"></i>
  </span>

  {{input-mask mask=format name=name class="form-control" unmaskedValue=value disabled=disabled}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the test is failing, but here are some suggestions on refactoring the component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from './template';

const  {
  Component,
  computed,
  get
} = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
  layout,

  // public
  disabled: false,
  value: null,

  // I'm guessing at what the `startsWith` helper does. Even if
  // `computed.match` doesn't do the correct thing, I'd keep the
  // `valueStartsWithFour` computed property and wrap whatever
  // logic you need in it.
  valueStartsWithFour: computed.match('value', /^04/),

  format: computed('valueStartsWithFour', function() {
    const valueStartsWithFour = get(this, 'valueStartsWithFour');

    return valueStartsWithFour ? '9999 999 999' : '(99) 9999 9999';
  }),

  iconName: computed('valueStartsWithFour', function() {
    const valueStartsWithFour = get(this, 'valueStartsWithFour');

    return valueStartsWithFour ? 'mobile' : 'phone';
  })
});
```

As a general rule of thumb, it's preferable to use computed properties when you can. From [the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/observers/):

> Observers are used heavily within the Ember framework itself, but for
>   most problems Ember app developers face, computed properties are the
>   appropriate solution.

Comment: Agree, your component is much better. Will be able to try this out Tuesday.

Comment: Why do you use `Ember.get(this, 'valueStartsWithFour')` as opposed to `this.get('valueStartsWithFour')`.  Is there a reason for this or is it just personal preference?

Comment: Short answer: consistency and `Ember.get()` works with both POJO and ember objects. More info: https://www.reddit.com/r/emberjs/comments/3mr5as/question_why_use_embergetthis_prop_instead_of/

Comment: OK, I like that it works with ordinary objects also.